# How to calculate after decimal point of 99.21(Base 10) to (Base 8)?

Tags: number-systems

As I know by 0.21 x8 and -4 for the answer to convert to base 8.

However, I could not calculate and keep on expanding the value to millions.

Comment: have you seen and followed http://m.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Octal. Can you convert .1 or 1/10 to base 8. What step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'm currently having problem to multiple 0.21 with 8 and -4 when the answer is 4

Answer (score 1):

$\frac18<0.21 <\frac28\\
0.21-\frac18 = 0.085\\
0.085*64 = 5.4\\
0.085 - \frac5{64} = 0.006875\\ 
0.006875 * 8^3 = 3.5\\
0.006875 - \frac 3{8^3} = 0.00101625\\
$

etc.

$0.153$